# Where is Paul pronounced like pole?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, british-english

I've heard "Paul" pronounced like "pole" and I wonder if that's a regular pronunciation for Americans and British people or if "pole" is just "Paul" mispronounced.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's possible you heard "Poul" as in the SF writer Poul Anderson.

Comment: It is _not_ a regular pronunciation in English. Maybe the Paul in question was of foreign origin.

Comment: Someone started a vote to close this as "opinion based".  I disagree strongly, as the question can be answered authoritatively with sources, even accounting for specific accents.  It's not opinion based at all-- it can be considered a *fact* whether or not this pronunciation is natural for this word anywhere within AmE or BrE.

Comment: @RichardWinters Agreed. I've left it open and answered it with verifiable facts

Comment: Pole sounds quite a bit like Paul if you're from Bolton though...

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the question is that there's no variety of English I'm familiar with of where "Paul" and "pole" are pronounced the same, so anyone thinking only in their own variety would conclude it's a mistake.

BUT the way British people pronounce "Paul", sounds very close to how North American speakers pronounce "pole", so someone familiar with NAm English might think a BrE speaker is pronouncing the name "Paul" like "pole".

"Paul":
NAm: /pɑl/
BrE: **/pɔːl/**

"Pole:"
NAm: **/poʊl/**
BrE: /pəʊl/

**/pɔːl/** and **/poʊl/** sound very similar, and are likely indistinguishable to most non-native speakers.